# MSMQ thottling with AppFabric hosted WF

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, msmq, appfabric

Scenario: WF service hosted in AppFabric. MSMQ transport. Throttling set to high values. MaxConcurrentCalls at 64.

Client sends 3000 requests in a burst.

Problem:MSMQ Listener Activator does not seem to respect throttling limits and once the number of currently executing instances rises, poison message exceptions begin to get raised.

I will later try working around this by setting WF instance to unload immediately when idle, which should help. Is there any way of configuring the activator to work with these limits, or any more solid solution?

Comment: What are your `<serviceThrottling/>` settings?

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this is can be caused by long running workflows (5+ seconds).

The MSMQ adapter reads messages in batches from the queue and pushes them to the workflow, quickly saturating capacity and resulting in timeouts and multiple delivery attempts, which will result in poison messages.

One thing to ensure is that in your service throttling settings the max instances > max calls, for example:

```
 <serviceThrottling 
       maxConcurrentCalls="5"
       maxConcurrentInstances="10" />
```

Comment: maxConcurrentInstances (and Sessions) is currently set to 20000. This is because I am processing end of day CSD transactions and 20000 is about our daily limit. maxConcurrentCalls is 64 because that is the default (16x4 processors) and it is less than 100 which is the default connection string MaxPoolSize connection limit. I want the MQ activator to respect the maxConcurrentCalls limit. Unloading the instances immediately seems not to be reliable, and also causes trouble (I discovered today) with persistence. I wonder if there is a way of configuring the activator in this scenario

Comment: another avenue I wonder about is the BufferedReceive behaviour's max pending message limit. The queued messages from the retry would get moved to the lock queue in batches of 64 if i set the max pending messages limit to 64.....this could avoid blowing the maxConcurrentCalls and avoid spamming the logs with exceptions?

Comment: I'm afraid my understanding is markedly less than yours. Sorry could not be more helpful.

Comment: SMSvcHost.exe.config has sections for net.pipe and net.tcp but not net.msmq - there must be something undocumented

Answer (score 0):

WF respects the MaxConcurrentCalls throttle only while inside a Receive-SendReply scope (i.e. WCF call still in progress). Since your using MSMQ binding and therefore one-way calls (Receive only) the MaxConcurrentCalls is basically irrelevant.

Use the MaxConcurrentInstances to control how many workflows are running/in memory. 20000 seems excessively high.